# How to find the same elements in two arrays and push them to form an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, date

I have an array of objects with dates that are same or different:

```
const obj = [

 {'date': '2021-12-13T02:32:24.911+00:00'
  'id' : 'id1'
 },
 {'date': '2021-12-15T02:54:06.248+00:00'
  'id' : 'id2'
 },
 {'date': '2021-12-15T02:54:06.248+00:00'
  'id' : 'id3'
 },
 {'date': '2021-12-14T02:54:06.248+00:00'
  'id' : 'id4'
 },
 {'date': '2021-12-17T02:54:06.248+00:00'
  'id' : 'id5'
 },
 {'date': '2021-12-17T02:54:06.248+00:00'
  'id' : 'id6'
 },

]
```

I also have an array with dates of the current week starting from Saturday:

```
const weekDates = ['12/11/2021', '12/12/2021', '12/13/2021', '12/14/2021', '12/15/2021', '12/16/2021', '12/17/2021']
```

Ultimately, I'd like to find the same dates exist in both arrays and push the identified objects from the obj array to a new object.

```
const newObject = {
'Sat' : [],
'Sun' : [],
'Mon' : [{'date': '2021-12-13T02:32:24.911+00:00'
         'id' : 'id1'}],
'Tue' : [{'date': '2021-12-14T02:54:06.248+00:00'
           'id' : 'id4'}],
'Wed' : [{'date': '2021-12-15T02:54:06.248+00:00'
          'id' : 'id2'},
         {'date': '2021-12-15T02:54:06.248+00:00'
          'id' : 'id3'}],
'Thu' : [],
'Fri' : [ {'date': '2021-12-17T02:54:06.248+00:00'
           'id' : 'id5'},
          {'date': '2021-12-17T02:54:06.248+00:00'
           'id' : 'id6'},]
}
```

What I've tried:

```
newDates.forEach(weekday => {
 obj.map(obj => {
  const date = new Date(obj.date).toLocaleDateString()
   if(date.includes(weekday)) {
    // some code here
   }
 })
})
```

Comment: These types of problems are almost always solved using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method. I strongly suggest learning that function. That and the [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) method of `Date`.

Comment: Soon you’ll be able to use the new groupBy array method

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, I had seen examples of how it works by creating a new array/object with reduce() but I always found it difficult to understand and use it effectively. I still have so much to learn....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `forEach` helper from `Array` and also `toLocaleDateString` helper from `Date`, like this:

```js
const obj = [
 {'date': '2021-12-13T02:32:24.911+00:00',
  'id' : 'id1'
 },
 {'date': '2021-12-15T02:54:06.248+00:00',
  'id' : 'id2'
 },
 {'date': '2021-12-15T02:54:06.248+00:00',
  'id' : 'id3'
 },
 {'date': '2021-12-14T02:54:06.248+00:00',
  'id' : 'id4'
 },
 {'date': '2021-12-17T02:54:06.248+00:00',
  'id' : 'id5'
 },
 {'date': '2021-12-17T02:54:06.248+00:00',
  'id' : 'id6'
 },
];
const weekDates = ['12/11/2021', '12/12/2021', '12/13/2021', '12/14/2021', '12/15/2021', '12/16/2021', '12/17/2021'];

const days =["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"]
const newObject= {Sat:[], Sun: [], Mon: [], Tue:[], Wed:[], Thu:[], Fri: []};

obj.forEach(item => {
    const dateObj = new Date(item.date)
    if( weekDates.includes( dateObj.toLocaleDateString() ) ){
        const day = days[dateObj.getDay()]
        newObject[day].push(item)
    }
})

console.log(newObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use some helpers, one array for the days, one object as reference to the days by taking a part if ISO string and collect all data to their days.

```js
const
    weekDates = ['12/11/2021', '12/12/2021', '12/13/2021', '12/14/2021', '12/15/2021', '12/16/2021', '12/17/2021'],
    days = ['Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
    objects = [{ date: '2021-12-13T02:32:24.911+00:00', id: 'id1' }, { date: '2021-12-15T02:54:06.248+00:00', id: 'id2' }, { date: '2021-12-15T02:54:06.248+00:00', id: 'id3' }, { date: '2021-12-14T02:54:06.248+00:00', id: 'id4' }, { date: '2021-12-17T02:54:06.248+00:00', id: 'id5' }, { date: '2021-12-17T02:54:06.248+00:00', id: 'id6' }],
    getISODate = s => s.replace(/^(..)\/(..)\/(....)$/, '$3-$1-$2'),
    reference = Object.fromEntries(
        weekDates.map((date, i) => [getISODate(date), days[i]])
    ),
    result = objects.reduce(
        (r, o) => (r[reference[o.date.slice(0, 10)]].push(o), r),
        Object.fromEntries(days.map(d => [d, []]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! This works but I think Saeed's answer is more closely aligned with my logic flow. Sadly I can only accept one answer.....

Answer (score 1):

For your specific problem, we can use [Date.prototype.toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) to get the day of the week and play with it.

```js
const firstArray = [{'date': '2021-12-13T02:32:24.911+00:00','id' : 'id1'}];
const secondArray = ['12/11/2021'];

const datesExistsInBothArrays = firstArray.filter(({ date, id } => {
  const firstArrayDate = new Date(date).valueOf();
  for (const secondDate of secondArray) {
    const secondArrayDate = new Date(secondDate).valueOf();
    if (firstArrayDate === secondArrayDate) return true;
  }
  return false;
});

const result = {};
for (const date of datesExistsInBothArrays) {
  const day = date.toDateString().split(' ')[0];
  if (result[day]) {
    result[day].push(date);
  } else {
    result[day] = [date];
  }
}
```